# If both checkboxes are true, then show DIV

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to show a Div that contains a button element, but only when BOTH checkboxes have been "agreed" to.
I have tried to use JS to check this and then set the style display when each checkbox is clicked.

HTML:

```
<div class="agreement_box">
  <input type="checkbox" id="box1" onclick="showMe('submit_btn')">
</div>
<br>
<div class="agreement_box">
  <input type="checkbox" id="box2" onclick="showMe('submit_btn')">
</div>

<div id="submit_btn" class="profileSubmit_btn" style="display:none">
  <button>
  BUTTON
  </button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function showMe(box) {
  var chbox1 = document.getElementByID("box1");
  var chbox2 = document.getElementByID("box2");
  var vis = "none";

  if (chbox1.checked && chbox2.checked) {
    vis = "block";
    break;
  }

  document.getElementById(box).style.display = vis;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nhykqodp/2/

I'm kinda new to JS and my HTML knowledge is about 10 years out of date at this point. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Comment: Theres quite a lot of syntax issues here, if you fix those it should work! Just follow along with the errors that you get in the console.

Comment: Why on earth would you suggest jQuery for such a thing @ŕ̷͉ge̸ḓ̶̅i̷t? [youmightnotneedjquery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Comment: Because Stackoverflow also uses jQuery @0stone0

Comment: That doesn't make sense at all... No jQuery is needed for such a simple check.

Comment: In fact, jQuery imo is a relic of the past. We're in 2021 and the world has been trying to get rid of any existing jQuery dependencies everywhere **for years**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I run your code, it shows:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement

Thats because a [`break`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp)
can only be used **inside** a loop.

---

Furthermore, you have a typo, it should be `getElementById` instead of `getElementByID`

<sup>**Note**: The `d` shouldn't be capitalised</sup>

---

- Remove the `break`
- Fix the typos:

```js
function showMe(box) {
  var chbox1 = document.getElementById("box1");
  var chbox2 = document.getElementById("box2");
  var vis = "none";

  if (chbox1.checked && chbox2.checked) {
    vis = "block";
  }

  document.getElementById(box).style.display = vis;
}
```

```html
<div class="agreement_box">
  <input type="checkbox" id="box1" onclick="showMe('submit_btn')">
</div>
<br>
<div class="agreement_box">
  <input type="checkbox" id="box2" onclick="showMe('submit_btn')">
</div>

<div id="submit_btn" class="profileSubmit_btn" style="display:none">
  <button>
  BUTTON
  </button>
</div>
```

---

Using an in-line if statement, we can remove the `vis` variable so we can alter the `style` right away like so:

```js
function showMe(box) {
  const chbox1 = document.getElementById("box1");
  const chbox2 = document.getElementById("box2");
  document.getElementById(box).style.display = (chbox1.checked && chbox2.checked) ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

```js
function showMe(box) {
  const chbox1 = document.getElementById("box1");
  const chbox2 = document.getElementById("box2");
  document.getElementById(box).style.display = (chbox1.checked && chbox2.checked) ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

```html
<div class="agreement_box">
  <input type="checkbox" id="box1" onclick="showMe('submit_btn')">
</div>
<br>
<div class="agreement_box">
  <input type="checkbox" id="box2" onclick="showMe('submit_btn')">
</div>

<div id="submit_btn" class="profileSubmit_btn" style="display:none">
  <button>
  BUTTON
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, this was exactly it! I would have looked over this a hundred times before I noticed the typo's. Works in both a fiddle and my site. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax errors have already been pointed out; for hiding/showing elements these already have an API which is called `el.hidden`. I recommend you use it.

Aside from that, you shouldn't use inline event handlers like `onclick`. Instead, use [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

I've also generalized your code, so that any number of checkboxes can act as toggle for any element, given that element has the `id` that you define in  `data-toggle` on the checkboxes.

```js
const checkboxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle]'));

function allChecked(toggle) {
  return checkboxes.filter(cb => cb.dataset.toggle === toggle).every(cb => cb.checked);
}

for (const checkbox of checkboxes) {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
    document.getElementById(this.dataset.toggle).hidden = !allChecked(this.dataset.toggle);
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="agreement_box">
  <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="submit_btn">
</div>
<br>
<div class="agreement_box">
  <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="submit_btn">
</div>

<div id="submit_btn" class="profileSubmit_btn" hidden>
  <button>
    BUTTON
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Little syntax error just replace document.getElementByID to document.getElementById